# Create service Wrapper in Python

Tags: python-3.x

We are trying to create a python servicewrapper to run python code in a windows machine, but the code is failing with errors. We are using anaconda library

```
            import win32service
            import win32serviceutil
            import win32event
            from application_input import appmain

            class PySvc(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
                # you can NET START/STOP the service by the following name
                _svc_name_ = "ApplicationPySvc"
                # this text shows up as the service name in the Service
                # Control Manager (SCM)
                _svc_display_name_ = "Application Service"
                # this text shows up as the description in the SCM
                _svc_description_ = "This service runs Application"

                def __init__(self, args):
                    win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
                    # create an event to listen for stop requests on
                    self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)

                # core logic of the service
                def SvcDoRun(self):
                    import servicemanager
                    appmain()

                    #import logging

                    #logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
                    #logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

                    # create a file handler
                    #handler = logging.FileHandler('output.log')
                    #handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

                    # create a logging format
                    #formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
                    #handler.setFormatter(formatter)

                    # add the handlers to the logger
                    #logger.addHandler(handler)

                    rc = None

                    # if the stop event hasn't been fired keep looping
                    while rc != win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                        # block for 5 seconds and listen for a stop event
                        rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, 5000)

                # called when we're being shut down
                def SvcStop(self):
                    # tell the SCM we're shutting down
                    self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
                    # fire the stop event
                    win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)


            if __name__ == '__main__':
                win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(PySvc)
```

We are getting the below errors whenever we try to run the service wrapper

> D:code>python appwinservicewrapper.py start Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File "dbmasterwinservicewrapper.py", line 56, in
>   win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(PySvc)   File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\win32serviceutil.py",
>   line 544, in HandleCommandLine
>       serviceClassString = GetServiceClassString(cls)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\win32serviceutil.py",
>   line 485, in GetServiceClassString
>       fname = os.path.join(path, win32api.FindFiles(fname)[0][8]) IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: place your error in box, select the error and press ctrl+k , It will be more clear that way

Comment: D:code>python appwinservicewrapper.py start Traceback (most recent call last): File "dbmasterwinservicewrapper.py", line 56, in win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(PySvc) File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\win32serviceutil.py", line 544, in HandleCommandLine serviceClassString = GetServiceClassString(cls) File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\win32serviceutil.py", line 485, in GetServiceClassString fname = os.path.join(path, win32api.FindFiles(fname)[0][8]) IndexError: list index out of range